# How to Use the If/else statement in PHP to filter mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

In the beginning, each person have 2 languages of messages (**chimessage** 
& **engmessage**)saved to the database.

Each of them have selected a **preferred** language (either chi or eng).
 In the display page, i'm trying to **show each person's message with their preferred language.**
eg, If person A prefer eng, the page will only show engmessage.

PS the display page will include **both engmessage and chimessage** for different people

I am wondering how can i do that, im thinking using the if/else statement.

PS I know iam using deprecated mysql,still trying to learn php, plz bear with me

```
 <?php

 include('connect-db.php');

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE language ='Chi' OR language ='Eng'");


 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

 echo "<tr>";

 echo '<td width="200px">' . $row['people'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td width="200px">' . $row['language'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $row['chimessage'] ."<br />";
 echo '<td>' . $row['engmessage'] ."<br />";

 }

 echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Expected result

```
 People      Language       Msg
 A            Chi           物理治療
 B            Eng           Physiotherapy
```

Comment: In your mysql query change 'AND' to 'OR'.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Can you add expected result also.

Comment: But still the display page show both languages of message for each people,

Comment: @Sahathulla , updated , please check

Comment: Given answer is useful or not.?

Comment: I am still trying, the if/else if statement dont seems to be working, i can echo the $row['chimessgge'];, but cant get it to work with the if/else if

Comment: Check the updated answer. In if else change <br> tag to </td> tag.

Comment: still only the $row[chimessage]/$row[engmessage] cant be display using the if/else if statement, any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151851/discussion-between-sahathulla-and-codezzz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
 <?php

 include('connect-db.php');

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE language ='Chi' OR language ='Eng'");


echo "<table>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

 echo "<tr>";
 echo '<td width="100px">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td width="200px">' . $row['people'] . '</td>';

 if($row['language'] == 'Chi')
 {
    echo '<td>' . $row['chimessage'] ."</td>";
 }
 else if($row['language'] == 'Eng')
 {
    echo '<td>' . $row['engmessage'] ."</td>";
 }
 echo "</tr>";

 }


 echo "</table>";
 ?>
```